# How to use diff3 with ed

Tags: diff, ed, diff3

How to use `diff3` together with `ed`? My attempt below does not match `diff3 --merge` output, so I must be doing something wrong.

Context: I've ported OpenBSD's [diff3prog.c](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/usr.bin/diff3/diff3prog.c) utility to be used in BusyBox, which has `diff` and `ed`.

```sh
cat <<- EOF > parent.txt
1
2
3
EOF

cat <<- EOF > ours.txt
1
2
3
EOF

cat <<- EOF > theirs.txt
1
2
3
4
EOF

f1=ours.txt
f2=parent.txt
f3=theirs.txt

diff3 --merge $f1 $f2 $f3 > merged_good.txt

diff3 -E $f1 $f2 $f3 | ed $f1
#prints:
#6
#?

mv $f1 merged_bad.txt
```

```sh
cat merged_good.txt
#prints:
#1
#2
#3
#4

cat merged_bad.txt
#prints:
#1
#2
#3
```

Comment: It seems that `diff3` output misses `w` ed command. So to get expected output, one should `(diff3 -E $f1 $f2 $f3; echo w) | ed $f1`. I wonder, why is this not mentioned in `diff3` docs? (can't find it...)

Comment: The only place I found this mentioned is some obscure https://www.mkssoftware.com/docs/man1/diff3.1.asp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(originally I posted this in the [comment above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65432496/how-to-use-diff3-with-ed#comment115682364_65432496). no-one added any further context, but the problem is solved, so I'm adding it as the answer as well)

It seems that `diff3` output misses `w` `ed` command. So to get expected output, one should `(diff3 -E $f1 $f2 $f3; echo w) | ed $f1`.